# NetworkX: how to add weights to an existing G.edges()?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, edges

Given any graph G created in NetworkX, I want to be able to assign some weights to  G.edges() **after** the graph is created. The graphs involved are grids, erdos-reyni, barabasi-albert, and so forth.

Given my `G.edges()`:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 10), (1, 11), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 12), ...]
```

And my `weights`:

```
{(0,1):1.0, (0,10):1.0, (1,2):1.0, (1,11):1.0, (2,3):1.0, (2,12):1.0, ...}
```

**How can I assign each edge the relevant weight?** In this trivial case all weights are 1.

I've tried to add the weights to G.edges() directly like this

```
for i, edge in enumerate(G.edges()):
    G.edges[i]['weight']=weights[edge]
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-6119dc6b7af0> in <module>()
     10 
     11 for i, edge in enumerate(G.edges()):
---> 12     G.edges[i]['weight']=weights[edge]

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

**What's wrong?** Since `G.edges()` is a list, why can't I access its elements as with any other list?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It fails because `edges` is a method.

The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.get_edge_data.html) says to do this like:

```
G[source][target]['weight'] = weight
```

For example, the following works for me:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_path([0, 1, 2, 3])

G[0, 1]['weight'] = 3

>>> G.get_edge_data(0, 1)
{'weight': 3}
```

However, your type of code indeed fails:

```
G.edges[0, 1]['weight'] = 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-97b10ad2279a> in <module>()
----> 1 G.edges[0][1]['weight'] = 3

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

---

In your case, I'd suggest

```
for e in G.edges():
    G[e[0], e[1]] = weights[e]
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I later need to access the edge data key associated with the weight (I need to compute the incidence matrix), what would that be in your example? I can't find it so I assume there isn't any. How to add it?

Comment: @CF84 Not really sure what "edge data key associated with the weight" means.

Comment: When you call `nx.incidence_matrix(G, nodelist=None, edgelist=None, oriented=False, weight=None)`, if you leave `weight=None` then all weights will be set at 1. Instead, to take advantage of your answer above, I need weights to be different. So the docs say that `weight` is a string that represents "the edge data key used to provide each value in the matrix". Now I've posted a trivial case where all weights are 1, but this was just a proof of principle.

Comment: @CF84 Still not sure I understand your question, but are you looking for an external `dict` mapping weights to edges?

Comment: Yes, this is what would be useful

Comment: @CF84 So in your loop, as you update the edge weights in the graph, also update this dictionary. Everything will then be cross-referenced.

Comment: The documentation link is broken. Might want to be https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.get_edge_data.html

Comment: Link of the Documentation needs to be updated. I don't know which specific page it should land on.

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html):

- You can set all the edge weights at once to the same value with

```py
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values = 1, name = 'weight')
```

- Given a dictionary with keys corresponding to edge tuples (your `weights`),
  you can assign edge weights to values from that dictionary with

```py
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values = weights, name = 'weight')
```

- To view and verify that these edge attributes have been set

```py
G.edges(data = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add edges like this:

`g1.add_edge('Mark', 'Edward', weight = 3)
g1.add_edge('Joseph', 'Michael', weight = 3)
g1.add_edge('Joseph', 'Jason', weight = 4)`

And then check whether the graph is weighted:

`nx.is_weighted(g1)`

> > > True

Categorize weights by their magnitude:

```
elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in g1.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 4]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in g1.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 4]
```

Next to display the weighted graph:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(g1)  # positions for all nodes
```

## nodes

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g1, pos, node_size=100)
```

## edges

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g1, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                   width=5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g1, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                   width=5, alpha=0.5, edge_color='g', style='dashed')
```

Comment: There are better APIs to set them all at once, this is not efficient

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question which is about adding weight to an existing edge.